# SharePoint 2013 - Large SharePoint_Config Database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, database, config-database

I have what appears to be a large SharePoint_config database:

```
SharePoint_Config.mdf = 99GB 
SharePoint_Config_Log.ldf = 14GB
```

Is this normal?  How can I decrease the size of this database?

Comment: What patch level are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not normal, config DB should be couple of gigs. If some cleanup jobs stop working then we can see the increase the size of config DB.

- check which table is larger in size. using table by size report.

We had problem in past, where "timer job history cleanup" timer job stop working and due to that no more purging in history tables and in a couple of months we were around 150GB,

Comment: The TimerJobHistory table has 235062785 records.  The Delete Job History is enabled and runs once a week.  The status shows failed on all previous jobs with a timeout error after 5 minutes.  I changed the job schedule to run every 15 minutes and can see that 100,000 records are deleted every time the job runs.  Thank you.

Comment: Great, that's it. Now you have to make a plan for shrinking the DBs after it purge all required entries....You are luck we were at 957Million records